# Why does my list include numbers bigger than the while loop?

Tags: java

I created a while loop with break statements inside it to print some numbers and avoid others and it ended up printing a number bigger the the limit of my loop. Here's the code

```
package examples;

public class LoopContolExamples {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count <= 12) {
        count++;

        if (count == 9)
            //break;
            continue;

        if (count % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        else
            System.out.println(count);{
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the result.
    3
    5
    7
    11
    13

Can anyone help explain what is going on?
*I'm new to Java and this is one of the first pieces of code I've written in the language.*

Comment: Well, you still enter the loop while the count is 12 and _then_, afterwards, inside the loop increment it to 13...

Comment: you must remove equals sign in the while loop if you want the values to be less than 12

Answer (score 5):

It entered the loop when `count` was equal to 12.

And then you immediately did `count++;`, making it 13, while it was still inside the loop. The next iteration would fail the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the value of count after incrementing it. So when it entered the loop, it will be 12 and then the value is incremented to 13 which then gets printed. Now if you want to print numbers leass than or equal to 12 then you need to change your code like this:

```
int count = 0;
            while (count < 12) {
                count++;

                if (count == 9)
                    //break;
                    continue;

                if (count % 2 == 0)
                    continue;
                else
                    System.out.println(count);{
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the range to be from 0 to 12, this is one alternative solution for this problem without changing the condition in the while loop.

```
     int count = 0;
     while (count <= 12) {
            if (count == 9)
                ; //do nothing
            if (count % 2 == 0)
                ; //do nothing
            else
                System.out.println(count); //otherwise, print the count
          count++; //increment the count
     }
```